# Looping through an array to check if a column is empty for an input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm stuck yet again and I don't know how to continue as I have starred myself blind to my jQuery functions.

What I want is to save the main table's columns in to an array, where I can check which one's empty. Then I want to send the value to the table. (3rd function).

Please help! I am stuck -_-

*JQUERY*

```
//function to save input value below the textbox in a "list" of columns.

$('#SaveButtonId').click(function () {
    $('.table2 tr .table2td').text($('input[type="text"]').val());
    $('input[type="text"]').val('');
});

//function to iterate through .mytd columns and put them in an array.
var columns = [];
$('.table').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.mytd:text').each(function() {
        columns.push($(this).val());
    });
});

//function to send value to empty column
$('#ActivateButton').click(function() {
    $('.table tr .mytd').text($('.table2td').val());
});
```

*HTML*

```
<div id="table-columns">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class ="tr-table">
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>

     <div class="row">
                    <div class="span2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="span8">
                        <div>
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" data-bind="visible: items().length > 0">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Items</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input id="Information"type="text"name="Information"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="SaveButtonId" type="submit" value="Save">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                            <table class="table2" style="border: 0;">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="table2td" style=" width: 100%"></td>
                                    <td id="Inputs"><input id="ActivateButton"          type="submit" value="Activate &#8679;" /><input id="DeleteButton" type="submit" value="Delete &#10092;" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

Comment: Add more code to ___[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mSUA/)___ and post it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mSUA/) of the code.

```
//function to save input value below the textbox in a "list" of columns.

$('#SaveButtonId').click(function () {
    $('.table2 tr .table2td').text($('input[type="text"]').val());
    $('input[type="text"]').val('');
});

//function to iterate through .mytd columns and put them in an array.
var columns = [];
$('.table').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.mytd:text').each(function() {
        columns.push($(this).val());
    });
});

//function to send value to empty column
$('#ActivateButton').click(function() {
    $('.table tr .mytd').text($('.table2td').val());
});
HTML

<div id="table-columns">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class ="tr-table">
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                            <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>

     <div class="row">
                    <div class="span2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="span8">
                        <div>
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" data-bind="visible: items().length > 0">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Items</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input id="Information"type="text"name="Information"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="SaveButtonId" type="submit" value="Save">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                            <table class="table2" style="border: 0;">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="table2td" style=" width: 100%"></td>
                                    <td id="Inputs"><input id="ActivateButton"          type="submit" value="Activate &#8679;" /><input id="DeleteButton" type="submit" value="Delete &#10092;" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you look for something like this to loop elements?

```
$("#table-columns tr td").each(function() { 
   var content = $(this).html(); 
});
```